# how to Add scroll view in to the android layout?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp.EmpDetail">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emp_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/reg_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emp_full_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/reg_fullname"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emp_username"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/reg_password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emp_full_name"/>


    <!-- Contact Detail -->
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contact Detail"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Email id"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Contact No"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I am new to android development, i am trying to add a scroll view in to the relative layout, everything was fine before adding a scroll view ,after adding a scroll view all of my relatively widgets misplacing and i try many solutions but it's not working for me. I am attaching screen shot of output.

[output is Without any action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkZWo.png)

[output with after clicking on edit text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcPLH.png)

Comment: Hello guys can u let me know y my question is down voted ?? i am new here if i will know then  from next time i will focus on my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Updated Code . Its working for me :) 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emp_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/reg_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emp_full_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/reg_fullname"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emp_username"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/user_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/reg_password"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emp_full_name"/>


        <!-- Contact Detail -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact Detail"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Email id"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contact"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_below="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Contact No"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following pattern :

```
<Linearlayout>
 ......
 <ScrollView>
 ......
 <RelativeLayout>
  //your view
 </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Set layout:width and layout:height match parent in all three layouts.

Comment: @Pranshu make linearlayout as parent layout and follow the structure above once..

Comment: i tried its still same.. only second contact view scrolling up .. parent view scrolling constant

Comment: @PranshuSingh if it really helped you to solve the problem .. bro , please do accept the answer  :D Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width = "match_parent"
   android:layout_height = "match_parent"
   android:fillViewport = "true">

  ....
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i try this one but its didn't work for me, wait i am sharing my code here

Comment: please review the code and let me know what is missing out.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:fillViewport="true">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/rltv1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dp">

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rltv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emp_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/reg_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emp_full_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/reg_fullname"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emp_username"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/user_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/reg_password"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emp_full_name"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Contact Detail -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rltv2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact Detail"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Email id"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Contact No"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: same problem with small changement